# How to set breakpoint in deployed ASPX file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, debugging

I have some ASPX files deployed in test machine which has IIS7 and Visual Studio 2008.

Now I attached to the w3wp process with VS2008 and open one ASPX file. The ASP file has some inline code like

```
<% DoSomthing() %>
```

I move the cursor to that line and press F9, but the status bar shows "This is not a valid location for a breakpoint". I have set below in web.config file.

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true">
```

So, how to set breakpoint for a deployed aspx file?

Comment: If you want to debug your code to see some intermediate values, you can make use of logging, etc.

Comment: In this case, I have to set break point to view the memory .

Comment: DoSomething() calls a method thats compiled into an Assembly, right? If that Assembly wasm't built in DEBUG mode then I don't think you can put breakpoints in ...

Comment: The assembly is built in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

You should have at least the same source code that was deplayed on the IIS server, attach the debugger to local machine(testing) connect to the database that is used by IIS application, and simulate the bug. You shouldn't have any problems. good luck.